# Can't get animation in Custom layout to work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'd like to create a layout that I can animate my items in. So when a dataprovider gets set on my List, the List's layout will then animate those items onto the screen.

So I've created a CustomLayout and added an update() function.

In the updateDisplayList the items are traced out just fine.

But in the update() function where I want to do the animation, the items are tracing out as null even though if I trace layoutTarget's numElement's I get four! If I use a setTimeout after setting the _dataProvider in my Main app of a second or two, then call update() in the ListLayout, then the traces work fine. So my question is, how can I ensure that I call update() to animate the items in when they are actually available??

Main app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:custom="*"
    creationComplete="handleCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var _dataProvider:ArrayCollection;
            public function set dataProvider(value:ArrayCollection):void
            {
                _dataProvider = value;
                listLayout.update();
            }

            private function handleCreationComplete():void
            {
                var arr:Array = new Array( { label:"1" }, { label:"2" }, { label:"3" }, { label:"4" } );
                dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(arr);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="list"
        dataProvider="{ _dataProvider }"
        labelField="label">
        <s:layout>
            <custom:ListLayout id="listLayout"  />
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

ListLayout:

```
package
{
    import mx.core.ILayoutElement;
    import spark.components.supportClasses.GroupBase;
    import spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author
     */
    public class ListLayout extends LayoutBase
    {
        public function update():void
        {
            var layoutTarget:GroupBase = target;
            //layoutTarget.autoLayout = false;

            var count:int = layoutTarget.numElements;
            trace(count); //traces 4

            for (var i:int = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var item:ILayoutElement = useVirtualLayout ? layoutTarget.getVirtualElementAt(i) :  layoutTarget.getElementAt(i);
                trace(item); //traces null
            }
        }

        override public function updateDisplayList(width:Number, height:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(width, height);

            var layoutTarget:GroupBase = target;

            var count:int = layoutTarget.numElements;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var item:ILayoutElement = useVirtualLayout ? layoutTarget.getVirtualElementAt(i) : layoutTarget.getElementAt(i);
                trace(item); //traces out the item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call **update** on your **listLayout**, you need to **validate** your "**list**" to make sure all the elements are available. So add one line **list.validateNow()** in **set dataProvider** *function* as below:

```
public function set dataProvider(value:ArrayCollection):void
{
    _dataProvider = value;
    list.validateNow();
    listLayout.update();
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! It was driving me insane!